# How can I right-justify variable length output?

Tags: text-processing, echo, table

So I don't want this:

```
echo "9"
9
```

Rather I need this, with e.g.: 4 spaces before it:

```
MAGICK "9"
    9
```

So if I try it with 10:

```
MAGICK "10"
   10
```

then it will just have 3 spaces before it. How can I format my output this way?

Comment: **3** spaces before `10` and **5** spaces before `9`? Is there some reason to it, just per-number whitespace or a mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ alias MAGICK="printf '%5s\n'"
$ MAGICK 10
   10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `printf` if you wish to format the output.

In your example above, you could use<sup>1</sup>:

```
printf "\t%s\n" "9"
```

Where `\t` is a tabspace, `%s` is the string your wish to print and `\n` is a newline.

Many shells have their own version of `printf` - check your documentation for details.

<sub>[1] Note: I am not entirely clear from your question what it is you are trying to accomplish...</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Adapted for piped output:

```bsh
alias rj='xargs printf "%$((${COLUMNS}-4))s\n"'

seq 0 $LINES | rj
```